# Change SVG image on hover in nav bar with CSS

Tags: css, image, svg, navigation

I'm using the following CSS to change an SVG image when a page is selected from the nav bar.

How do I change it back to its original image on hover?

```
.left_nav > li.opened_menu > a.about-us:after {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64, SVG ENCODING CODE");}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :visited instead of :after.

```
 .left_nav > li.opened_menu > a.about-us:visited { background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml; base64, SVG ENCODING CODE");}
```

The ::after pseudo-element can be used to insert some content after the content of an element. -W3schools
I don't think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

By Adding :hover:after to the last child element it changes the SVG image on hover.

```
.left_nav > li.opened_menu > a.about-us:hover:after {background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,SVG ENCODING CODE");}
```